# Rails, Mongoid and complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

User has_many items
Item belongs_to Client

Using mongoid (i don't think it's mongoid specific, but anyway) i need to gather all clients by given user. Currently i use:

```
@clients = current_user.items.map{|c| c.client}
```

but for sure it's not good, and not acceptable. What is the best way for implementation?

Comment: That's not horrible or anything.  But it's probably best if you describe via some pseudo code what you'd like your ultimate syntax to look like.  Basically it sounds like you'd like to apply some syntactic sugar to your code,  and have cleaner code,  maybe something like:  clients = user.all_clients

Comment: First of all, as result is have an array, and it's not very handy. Second, i'm not sure, but i think with huge amount of records it's not good to put it on ruby's shoulders? (again, it's mongodb)

Comment: Got it, I think you have a couple of options,  either hand craft a SQL statement that does what you want,  or use ActiveRecord includes (Eager loading). Deciding between the two is probably application specific. [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)  Check out section on Eager Loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not run into the N+1 problem I would do something like this.

```
# first you retrieve all client ids
ids = current_user.items.map(&:client_id)

# then you retrieve all clients at once
@clients = Client.in(id: ids)
```